# Extremely Slow for Selenium Webdriver to get URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to learn Selenium today but it takes around 9 seconds to just to get the URL, any suggestions? Running on a new 2022 Mac.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
start_time = time.time()

url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())) #this takes about 5 seconds

#tried those things, didn't help
# options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
# options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
# options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
# options.add_argument('-no-sandbox')
# # options.add_argument('headless')
# options.add_argument('-disable-dev-shm-usage')
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)




driver.get(url) #takes another 5 seconds
print("hi")
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Tried "headless" option as well. Auto Proxy is also off in the setting.

I'd expect to have the code finish within 1 second.

Comment: what if you try to run chrome without any option?

Comment: Where do you define `start_time` ?

Comment: @soundwave without any option that would take 15-18 seconds...

Comment: @AlexeyR. at the very beginning after import... I didn't included it in the code above

Comment: Try using this definition of the driver `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(chromedriver_path))` where the path is something like `chromedriver_path = r'C:\Users\username\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\108.0.5359.71\chromedriver.exe'`